# How to element-wise subtract to in a keras Dense layer in tensorflow2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Let say I'm at the `Dense(2)` layer. How to add layers to first log the whole tensor and then element-wise subtract the second column from the first column? Thank you.

```
array([[1,2],
       [3,4],
       [5,6]])

becomes

array([[log(2)-log(1)],
       [log(4)-log(3)],
       [log(6)-log(5)]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(input)
x = tf.math.log(x[-1][0]) - tf.math.log(x[-1][1])
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)
```

Or you have to create a custom layer.

Comment: Is there a difference between using tf.math and tf.keras.backend?

Comment: Good question. I didn't use tf.keras.backend. Actually I was not aware of it. I would recommend to post this question to SO